# Protection against multiple click on a link

Tags: python, django

I have a web site made with Django 1.7. The user can click on a link but it's take a while before rendering because of some server works.

How can I disable correctly the link after the first click ? I know I can do it with some javascript but I just want to know if there is another way.

Just for precision, this is my link:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/ds9s/view/">Let's go !</a>
```

Thanks for reading and maybe answering !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the parameters for what you need:

1) It needs to be client side. Server side makes no sense for tracking UI clicks

2) It needs to be fast.

It would seem that javascript meets both criteria. Why not just use that to disable the click? You are going to have a page load when the server responds, so it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Okay ! It's what I thinking. Thanks !